# Reading and Writing Raw PGM Files in Java

Tags: java, pgm

I am trying to read and write PGM Files. Working with ASCII PGM (Magic number = P2) is easy, but I am having some confusion in working with Raw PGM Files (magic number P5).

Here is the PGM file that I am trying to read : [A.pgm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9znbcsplx8phuxo/A.pgm?dl=0)

After PGM Header, when I try to read the Image data using the following Java code :

```
FileInputStream inRaw = null;
try {
    inRaw = new FileInputStream("A.pgm");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Scanner scan_Raw = new Scanner(inRaw);
//lines to read the PGM Header
System.out.println(scan_Raw.nextLine());
System.out.println(scan_Raw.nextLine());
System.out.println(scan_Raw.nextLine());
System.out.println(scan_Raw.nextLine());
//Code to read the Image Data
while(scan_Raw.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(scan_Raw.next());
```

Then it gives the following output:

```
�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������#F�����������������   ����������������}   ����������������; > e���������������� #��������������� 7� ��������������v y�M ��������������4 
`�������������     
������������� A��� ������������p ����U ������������n�����
��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

What is this output?
Also why I am unable to read the while by using `scan_Raw.nextByte();` (input mismatch exception) because as I understand the image data in P5 is saved as Bytes?

Comment: The problem is, you can't use `Scanner` (which is for text input) to parse raw bytes. Instead, use the scanner only for parsing the header, then - if the format is `P5` - read the bytes directly from the  `InputStream`, using the `read()` or `read(b, off, len)` methods. In many ways, reading the `P5` format is actually easier, as the data is already in the native format used by `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY`.

Comment: PS: I'm assuming you want to write your own reader/writer for educational purposes. If not, have a look at my [PNM plugin for ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/tree/master/imageio/imageio-pnm/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/plugins/pnm), which supports reading PBM, PGM, PPM and other derivates.

Comment: @haraldK Yes it is for learning. Thanks for the plugin, I can learn from it.